# Rails query with condition in count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having a little trouble with a query in Rails.

Actually my problem is:

> I want to select all `users` which do not have any `user_plans` **AND** his `role.name` is equals to *default*... **OR** has `user_plans` and all `user_plans.expire_date` are lower than *today*

`user` has_many `roles`

`user` has_many `user_plans`

```
users = User.where(gym_id: current_user.id).order(:id)
@users = []
for u in users
  if u.roles.pluck(:name).include?('default')
    add = true
    for up in u.user_plans
      if up.end_date > DateTime.now.to_date
        add = false
      end
    end
    if add
      @users << u
    end
  end
end
```

This code up here, is doing exactly what I need, but with multiple queries.
I don't know how to build this in just one query.

> I was wondering if it is possible to do something like
>
> `where COUNT(user_plans.expire_date < TODAY) == 0`

Comment: User.where(gym_id: current_user.id).where COUNT((user_plans.expire_date < TODAY) == 0).order(:id)

Comment: just use `joins` ?!?

Comment: @Jyotimishra I want to know the exactly syntax for this query, but thanks

Comment: @Fallenhero as mentioned in comment above, I'm having trouble with the exact syntax for this query in Rails

Comment: Guys i know how to use the .joins(~) but I don't know how to perform a "count with condition"

Answer (score 0):

```
User.joins(:user_plans, :roles).where("roles.name = 'default' OR user_plans.expire_date < ?", Date.today)
```

Should work, not tested, but should give you some idea you can play with (calling `.distinct` at the end may be necessary)

There is also where OR in Rails 5:

```
User.joins(:user_plans, :roles).where(roles: { name: 'default' }).or(
  User.joins(:user_plans).where('user_plans.expire_date < ?', Date.today)
)
```

FYI: Calling .joins on User will only fetch those users who have at least one user_plan (in other words: will not fetch those who have no plans)